# Make image and text appear side by side within button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to have a button that has a small icon and text inside the button, the icon is sitting way to the left of the button, how can I move it closer to the text which is centered?

This is my XML for the button:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:text="BACK"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:width="160dp"
        android:height="70dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do with `drawableLeft` attribute. This attribute positions the image to the far left position (no matter where your text is).

You need to create your own button for this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="160dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BACK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't move it closer. Your only option if you want to have them closer together is building your own button:

```
<RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rlButton"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_text"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use a margin to control the distance between the `TextView` and `ImageView`. You can use it pretty much the same as a button:

```
RelativeLayour rlButton = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlButton);
rlButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    ....
});
```

But of course you have to apply your button style to the RelativeLayout so it looks the same as a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
 android:text="Drawable left"/>
```